# unit test of domain classes in spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

Strangely, I have not found any guides, tutorials, examples, videos, etc about how specifically make unit testing of domain classes in an application developed using spring boot 2. Domain classes are using JPA annotations.

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can test entity classes like other classes in a unit test. You can use the constructor for it.

Comment: Usually domain classes did not contains any logics for test. Just simply getters and setters + database annotations. What want you test???

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have realized that TDD supported by Spring Test is a whole subject by itself. And, Spring Test has been evolving through time as any other aspect of the Spring framework. So, instead of reading internet tutorials, rather I am studying spring reference manuals. Question closed.